# Storing a scripts last run time in PHP

Tags: php, time

I need to store the time of the last run of a script to make sure it doesn't read old items (tweets in this case). Whats the best way to keep track of this?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a timestamp and save it to a logfile that can be read on the next iteration.

```
$time_ran = time();

function saveTimeRan(){
  $fh = fopen('/path/to/a/new/log' 'w+');
  fwrite($fh, $time_ran);
  fclose($fh);
}

function getTimeRan(){
  $fh = fopen('/path/to/a/new/log' 'r+');
  $time = fgets($fh);
  fclose($fh);
  return $time;
}
```

Might I suggest you make this an object and put the contents of saveTimeRan in the magic __destruct function, so when your object is GC'ed it will save the time.  Just a suggestion.  You could put your tweet functions in other object methods and make one comprehensive interface. You could, alternatively, save the value to a database field and call it each iteration.

Comment: Remember to set file permissions!

Comment: Thank you. This worked flawlessly and your warning came in handy.

Comment: @Arbiter - glad to help - Since you're new, just be aware you can check the green check mark next to the answer that worked for you and vote up for others that work as well.

Answer (score 2):

You gave zero information on specifics, so I will be general.

1. Store it in a database like MySQL
2. Write it to a local file with `file_put_contents()` and read it with `file_get_contents()`
3. Touch a local file with one of the os functions, and then stat the file to see it's mtime
4. Use `sqlite` to write it to a local database

Answer (score 2):

> Whats the best way to keep track of
>   this?

The best way is to keep track of that in memory(redis/apc/memcached/etc)(back upped by any persistent store(mysql/mongodb/redis/etc). You should try to avoid to touch the disc(I/O) because that's very  very slow compared to speed of memory.

### Redis

You can configure redis two ways:

- write data back to persistent asynchronously(snapshotting) after certain time has passed and or keys have been modified.
- write data back to persistent store immediately(append-only).

It's a trade-off(performance vs safety)

### APC/Memcached

APC and Memcached don't have persistent storage so you have to do that using for example mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You could store time stamps in a DB or a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the script write a timestamp/date to a text file every time it runs. Then you can optionally read the file before running the script to make sure you don't run it again before x amount of time has passed or only run if a certain condition is true.

Check out [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

-Ryan